# Not sure why this isnt rendering

Tags: java, render, libgdx

So I have a splash image that is not rendering and I'm not really sure why. I have done the correct process, creating anew sprite and then in my render method rendering it with the batch like so:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    splashSprite.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}


@Override
public void show() {
    splashSprite = new Sprite(new Texture("data/xidstudios_splash.png"));

    batch = new SpriteBatch();
}
```

As you can see, I have done the correct process of steps, am I missing one?

Answer (score 1):

```
public void render(float delta) {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    batch.begin();
    splashSprite.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must provide the viewports to opengl either using a camera or directly calling the opengl func so that your projection are currectly set to view the image